# Missing Auxiliary Verb in the "The more" Structure?

Tags: sentence-structure

Why is the first part of this sentence correct?

> The more thoughtful your ambitions, and the more clearly you can explain them, the higher your chances of admission.

Shouldn't it be "The more thoughtful your ambitions [ARE]" ?

Maybe both sentences are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right; they are both correct.

> Shouldn't it be The more thoughtful your ambitions [ARE] ?

You've almost answered your own question here: the word "are" is implied, and elided. The listener or reader can infer it based on context, as you and I have.

cf.:
*The bigger the lie [is], the more people believe it*

Or even: *The more [people are present], the merrier [those people are]*

Comment: Your answer is very clear :). 
I also wonder whether there is a grammatical rule that tells us when can we elide words in a sentence? If there is a rule, what's it called?

Comment: The way we omit words in a sentence just seems pretty random to me. Can I elide words in formal letters? Does it make my writing style casual?